# Remove line break inside line row from CSV with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, csv

Hello I have this text :

```
1,0.00,,2.00,10,"Block. CertNot Valid.
Query with me",2013-06-20,0,0.00
```

This is two lines in CSV file, but really is one line of data and I want remove the break line, and put this line in just one line using Regular Expressions.

I've tried: `(\")(.*)(\n)(.*)(\")` , but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not just use the `csv` module to read this? It'll handle the linebreak correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't. There is **no need** to remove the line break.

Use the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to read the CSV file, it'll handle the linebreak correctly:

```
import csv

with open(csvfilename, 'rb') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        print repr(row[5])
```

will print:

```
'Block. CertNot Valid.\nQuery with me'
```

for that row.

This works because that column is correctly quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can check result here: https://www.debuggex.com/r/2_X5N-wTLZ2laJKh

Console output:

```
>>> regex = re.compile("\"(.+?)\"",re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL|re.VERBOSE)
>>> regex.findall(string)
[u'Block. CertNot Valid.\nQuery with me', u'test\naaa', u'bbb\nvvvv']
```

And 'string' value is:

```
1,0.00,,2.00,10,"Block. CertNot Valid.
Query with me",2013-06-20,0,0.00

1,0.00,,2.00,10,"test
aaa",2013-06-20,0,0.00

1,0.00,,2.00,10,"bbb
vvvv",2013-06-20,0,0.00
```